# How to add geom_line to an existing plot using another data set

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to add an additional time series curve to an existing plot.

Here is code for the current plot:

```
lims <- as.POSIXct(strptime(c("2015-9-2 00:00","2015-9-3 00:00"), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), tz="UTC")

ggplot(subset(DF, ID %in% c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")),
       aes(x = DateTime, y = Temp, group = ID, colour = ID)) +
   geom_point(alpha = 0.4, size = 0.8) +
   scale_x_datetime(limits = lims, breaks = date_breaks("4 hour"),
                    labels = date_format("%m/%d %H:%M")) +
   scale_colour_manual(values = c("green4", "red", "plum", "gold2", "dodgerblue"),
                       breaks = c("A" , "B" , "C" , "D", "E"),
                       labels = c("N", "E", "W", "S", "C"))
```

How to add a `geom_line` which uses data from another data set (`DF_other$Temp`) to the existing plot?

Comment: "The trick is that _each layer can have its own dataset_." Thus, you can have `+ geom_line(data = onedataset) + geom_line(data = anotherdataset)`

Comment: I need to add "data = " .... that's for helping me!!